# Is there an equivalent to python reduce() function in scala?

Tags: python, scala, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

I've just started learning Scala and functional programming and I'm trying to convert the following from Python to Scala:

```
def immutable_iterative_fibonacci(position):

    if (position ==1):
        return [1]

    if (position == 2):
        return [1,1]

    next_series = lambda series, _: series + [series [-1] + series [-2]]
    return reduce(next_series, range(position - 2), [1, 1])
```

I can't figure out what the equivalent of reduce in Scala is. This is what I currently have. Everything works fine except the last line.

```
def immutable_fibonacci(position: Int) : ArrayBuffer[Int] = {

    if (position == 1){
          return ArrayBuffer(1)
     }

     if (position == 2){
         return ArrayBuffer(1,1)
     }

     var next_series = (series: ArrayBuffer[Int]) => series :+ ( series( series.size - 1) + series( series.size -2))

     return reduce(next_series, 2 to position, ArrayBuffer(1,1))
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the last line?  Do you get a compiler error (if so, what is it), incorrect results (if so, what are they and why are they wrong), a runtime error (if so, what is it), ...?

Answer (score 10):

Summary of Python [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), for reference:

```
reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])
```

### Traversable

A good type to look at is [`Traversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable), a supertype of `ArrayBuffer`. You may want to just peruse that API for a while, because there's a lot of useful stuff in there.

### Reduce

The equivalent of Python's `reduce`, when the `initializer` arg is omitted, is Scala's [`Traversable[A]#reduceLeft`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable@reduceLeft[B>:A](op:(B,A)=>B):B):

```
reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B
```

The `iterable` arg from the Python function corresponds to the `Traversable` instance, and the `function` arg from the Python function corresponds to `op`.

Note that there are also methods named `reduce`, `reduceRight`, `reduceLeftOption`, and `reduceRightOption`, which are similar but slightly different.

### Fold

Your example, which does provide an `initializer` arg, corresponds to Scala's [`Traversable[A]#foldLeft`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable@foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B):

```
foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

The `initializer` arg from the Python function corresponds to the `z` arg in `foldLeft`.

Again, note that there are some related methods named `fold` and `foldRight`.

### Fibonacci

Without changing the algorithm, here's a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
def fibonacci(position: Int): Seq[Int] =
  position match {
    case 1 => Vector(1)
    case 2 => Vector(1, 1)
    case _ =>
      (2 to position).foldLeft(Vector(1, 1)) { (series, _) =>
        series :+ (series(series.size - 1) + series(series.size - 2))
      }
  }
```

A few miscellaneous notes:

- We generally never use the `return` keyword
- Pattern matching (what we're doing with the `match` keyword) is often considered cleaner than an `if`-`else` chain
- Replace `var` (which allows multiple assignment) with `val` (which doesn't) wherever possible
- Don't use a mutable collection (`ArrayBuffer`) if you don't need to. `Vector` is a good general-purpose immutable sequence.

And while we're on the topic of collections and the Fibonacci series, for fun you may want to check out the first example in the [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) documentation:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #::
  fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map { n => n._1 + n._2 }

fibs.drop(1).take(6).mkString(" ")
// "1 1 2 3 5 8"
```

Comment: Or, just for comparison, the most concise Fibonacci `Stream` I've ever encountered (so far): `val fib: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1:BigInt)(_+_)`